# Create dependency list from WORKSPACE in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

I'd like to maintain a list of dependencies and their versions per Bazel project.

How do I query for WORKSPACE rules the BUILD rules depend on? How can I access the contained attributes?

**EDIT** I'd like to query based on a BUILD rule. So if I have multiple rules, I only want the WORKSPACE info based on the one I asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I did this was to keep the workspace deps in a separate format, iterate them, and then build a markdown document.

See https://github.com/pubref/rules_protobuf/blob/master/DEPENDENCIES.md

https://github.com/pubref/rules_protobuf/blob/master/protobuf/internal/proto_dependencies.bzl

There's probably a way to do it via a genquery and native.existing_rules, but I have not tried that.

HTH, 
Paul

Comment: Thank you, I used the pubref rules first but wanted to stay as close to the bazel-repo rules as possible. They still helped me tremendously in understanding Bazel and Skylark.
I can't upvote yet (rep score too low) and I'd like to hold out for an answer using bazel query, so I won't mark yours as an answer yet.
But what you describe is exactly what I will be doing if rules won't help.